# Magento 2 how to create shipment in order event?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipment

I'm trying to create the shipment of the order just after the order is created. I'm using the event `sales_order_place_after`.

Here is my code
, I'm running this method in execute(), and getting the order with  `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`

```
 public function createShipment($order){
        $this->logger->info("Inside Shipment function");
        $orderShipment = $this->_convertOrder->toShipment($order);

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {

         $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
         $shipmentItem = $this->_convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qty);
         $orderShipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
        }

        $orderShipment->register();
        $orderShipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

        try{
             // Save created Order Shipment
             $orderShipment->save();
             $orderShipment->getOrder()->save();

             // Send Shipment Email
             $this->_shipmentNotifier->notify($orderShipment);
             $orderShipment->save();
             $this->logger->info("SHIPMENT CREATED!!!!");



        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __($e->getMessage())
            );
        }

    }
```

When I try to place the order in frontend, I get the following error>

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I think you did the little mistake here, you should avoid those items which has parent_item.

*So, changes below code*

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
```

**to**

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
if ($orderItem->getParentItem()) : continue;
```

Comment: Hello, I modified my code and now it puts the order in processing, however Shipments of the order is empty